# Resolve dynamic nested tabs with privleges in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, tabs

I have two levels of tabs in angular application[**See Image1**],
The 2nd level tabs is privilege controlled, i.e., if the user has access to the tab it will show otherwise not. For ex:, On clicking the Dashboard Tab if user has access to only SelfService2, by default user should be able to see SelfService2 component and that tab should be active.

I have a TabComponent which is common for rendering the second level tabs.
Normal routing works fine, i.e., if I click on Dashboard then based on the privilege whichever is the first component that will be visible to user.

I am facing issue if I click on Dashboard again, in this case the second level tabs are shown but the default component is not rendered[**See Image2**]

[Image1 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHtxn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHtxn.png)

[Image2 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Vcs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Vcs.png)

**Stackblitz**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-reyyk9

I am not able to figure out how to detect the default route when clicking on the parent tab, setting the default route in routing module is not an option since I want it to be dynamic, I was thinking if there could be a way where we can dynamically set the default route for the children routes.